# SQLite trigger with user-defined function

Tags: c#, sqlite, triggers

I'm trying to create a SQLite trigger to call a function in C#. The function should be called after updating one of the columns in the table.

**The function is defined as follows:**

```
public class TestingFunction<T1> : SQLiteScalarFunction<T1, string>
{
     public TestingFunction() : base("testing") { }

     protected override string Execute(T1 arg1, SQLiteConnection connection)
     {
         //.. do some work
     }
}
```

**and registered:**

```
SQLiteConnection sqLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + settings.db_source);
sqLiteConnection.Open();
TestingFunction<string> function = new TestingFunction<string>();
sqLiteConnection.RegisterFunction(function);
```

**The trigger:**

```
create trigger trigger1 update of act_cost on tunnels
begin
   select testing(db_source);
end;
```

When updating the table, I'm getting SQLite error: `no such function: testing.`

Any suggestions on what the problem might be?

Comment: From which connection are you calling the `UPDATE` that triggers the trigger?

Comment: You are totally right, I was creating a new connection for the Update. Now it finally works. Thanks!

Comment: Can you update this with the code that works?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger tries to reach a function in your database called testing and apparently it does not exist. So, you should check whether the function exists in the scheme of your database. Try to call it manually. If it does not exist, implement it.

Comment: I can call the function from the code as SQLiteCommand with .ExecuteScalar() and everything works just fine. But when I try to call it from the trigger it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the trigger and the function in the same database?